# Задание: Использовать 6 разных exception

Tags: python, исключения, try

Мы только изучаем функции, но нам задали такое задание. Не знаю как решить, интернет не помог.

```
class MyError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
​
class Travel():
    def __init__(self, country, transport, days, eat, price):
        self.country = country
        self.transport = transport
        self.days = days
        self.eat = eat
        self.price = price
    def display(self):
        print("Country: {}"
              " Transport: {}"
              " Days: {}"
              " Eat: {}"
              " Price: {}".format(self.country, self.transport, self.days, self.eat, self.price))
​
class Health(Travel):
    def __init__(self, country, transport, days, eat, price):
        super().__init__(country, transport, days, eat, price)
    def display(self):
        print("Country: {}"
              "\tTransport: {}"
              "\tDays: {}"
              "\tEat: {}"
              "\tPrice: {}".format(self.country, self.transport, self.days, self.eat, self.price))
​
a1 = Health("France", "Airplane", 7 ,3, 200)
a2 = Travel("Dubai", "Airplane", 14, 3, 300)
a3 = Travel("Germany", "Airplane", 7, 3, 120)
e = [a2, a3]
e1 = [a1]
​
p = True
while p:
    print("Оптимальный ценник для вас")
    print(120, 200, 300)
    print("1. Путешествие лечение")
    print("2. Путешествие отдых")
    print("3. Exit")
    price = input("Введите оптимальный ценник: ")
    n = input("Введите n: ")
    try:
        n = int(n)
        price = int(price)
        if n == 1:
            for i in e1:
                if price >= i.price:
                    i.display()
        elif n == 2:
            for i in e:
                if price >= i.price:
                    i.display()
        elif n == 3:
            break
        if n != 1 and n != 2 and n != 3:
            print("Ошибка")
        else:
            "Нет запрошенной вами информации"
    except ValueError:
        print("Введите данные правильно!")
    except NameError:
        print("Ошибка")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("KeyboardInterrupt is caught")
    except AttributeError:
        print("Something")
    except IndexError:
        print("try to find index error")
    except MyError as mr:
        print(mr)

p = False
```

Это мой код, много неправильного.

Comment: а задачу вы озвучивать не будете? только решение? и что вы хотите то?

Comment: Можете указать ошибки и помочь понять исключения?

Comment: а вы можете хотя бы написать где именно возникает у вас ошибка и на каких данных :)))) и что именно в исключениях вам бы хотелось понять

Comment: Он учитыввает только 1 исключение, остальное видимо неправильно написано.

Comment: Остальные нужно ещё придумать, как инициировать

Comment: Вообще понятия не имею, как добавить их.

Comment: что-то мне кажется, что если вы вообще не в теме - лучше почитать полные описания про исключения, потому что тут коротенько можно только частные случае какие-то задеть, вообще когда срабатывает исключение, то выполнение кода в блоке `try` прекращается и управление отдается в блок `except`, в ту его часть, которая соответствует указанному исключению. Вы хотите, чтобы для разных ситуаций срабатывали разные исключения или что? Вы же не сами код написали - какая была цель задания?

Comment: нихера нен понял, поэтому и зашел в стек за помощью.